# C# LINQ Query with Calculated Field and Subquery in a Select Clause

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, subquery, calculated-field

I'm writing a LINQ query in my C# project as below but the compiler doesn't like the calculated field 'Enabled'.

It says the comparison between (a.Qtty * a.Price) and the subquery can't be done because the types are different. The first one is double and the second is an anonymous type.

I've tried all sorts of casts but didn't get it to work.

I've removed the where clauses to make it simpler and the optionTypes is an enum.

If I remove the comparison between the calculated value and the subquery it works fine.

Any help?

```
dynamic fromOthers = _ctx.Orders
  .Where( /* conditions */ )
  .Select(a => new
    {
      Id = a.Id,
      Option = a.OpType == OptionTypes.Buy ? "Buy" : "Sell",
      Enabled = 
        (a.OpType == OptionTypes.Buy 
          ? (a.Qtty * a.Price) <= 
            _ctx.Items
              .Where( /* conditions */ )
              .Select(b => new
              {
                    b.Qtty
              })
              .FirstOrDefault() ? "Yes" : "No"
          : "TBD"
        )
      })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Maybe show the definition of `a`.

Comment: Sorry? I didn't understand your question..

Comment: You're comparing `new { b.Qtty }` to a numeric value. Just select `b.Qtty` without wrapping it into an anonymous type.

Comment: @GertArnold please post this as an answer

Comment: Yeah. It worked fine! Post as an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

You compare a numeric value (I guess a `decimal`) to an anonymous type:

```
(a.Qtty * a.Price)
<= 
_ctx.Items.Where().Select(b => new { b.Qtty }).FirstOrDefault()
```

To fix this, don't create the anonymous type but just select the value:

```
(a.Qtty * a.Price)
<= 
_ctx.Items.Where().Select(b => b.Qtty).FirstOrDefault()
```